# Visual Studio - Android Ui Designer not rendering

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

When opening the Android UI Designer in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 it does not render the view correctly. It only looks like this:
[image: Screenshit Android UI Designer in Visual Studio]

The view is correctly displayed in Xamarin Studio on my colleagues' PCs and is rather simple. I even tried starting a new sample project in VS. Same problem there.
Anybody has an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio usually struggles in designer, especially when there are loads of features or complex resources etc. Best method is to just ignore the designer and always use code view. Alternatively Android studio has a good designer if it is a necessity.

Hope i could help.